# Symmetry breaking under isothermal expansion

Tags: phase-transition, symmetry-breaking

Is there any example of a symmetry breaking phase transition in a system of particles under isothermal expansion?

Comment: I would say, that a spin gas should undergo a magnetic phase transition as you expand it, because the interaction gets weaker with the average distance of the spins, even as T stays constant. Is that what you are looking for? Maybe there is a more simple example, this is just the first thing that came to my mind.